# Is there a way to load an installed add-in from a workbook that is using a "startfromscratch" ribbon?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I am using an add-in to open a workbook with a button. The workbook uses a startfromscratch ribbon so the add-in disappears when the workbook is opened.  I tried using addins("AddInName").installed = false followed by addins("AddInName").installed = true on Workbook_Open.  The issue with that is since the workbook is opened using the add-in, it faults the code. So I am looking for a way to open this workbook with the only thing in the ribbon being my add-in.

Below is the code that I use to open the workbook:

```
Sub ViewRequest()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim ViewRequest As Workbook

    With New frmEditCopy
        .FormatForm ViewForm
        .Show
        If .ClickedOk Then
            FilePath = Dir$(TestReqFolder & TestNumberToEdit & "*")
            If FilePath <> "" Then
        '////////This is the workbook that opens with no ribbon/////////
                Set ViewRequest = Workbooks.Open(TestReqFolder & FilePath, , True)
                ViewRequest.Activate
                Set ViewRequest = Nothing
            Else
                MsgBox "Test Request does not exist"
            End If
        End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Kinda depends on how you opened the workbook. You can open it in the same Application context or you might have created a new application context. Can you show us the code that opens?

Comment: @HackSlash, I added the code that shows the opening.  Do you think that it would make more sense to open an additional instance of excel to open the workbook that way the code still runs in the original instance?

Comment: No, this looks like you are using the default application context. So anything you do here would effect the current Excel instance. Does the ribbon look correct before you open the new workbook? The documentation says you need to set the StartFromScratch before the add-in is loaded for the first time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.officeribbon.startfromscratch?view=vsto-2017

Comment: @HackSlash, So the add-in is always loaded when excel is open, the goal is to open the separate workbook using the add-in and hide the rest of the ribbon except for my custom tab.

Comment: Sounds like you need code to hide all the ribbon elements.

Comment: Startfromscratch = true hides all of the ribbon elements, its showing the add-in that I created in the workbook that I am having difficulties with.  So far the only thing that has worked is to add the xml code into the workbook, but that makes the workbook file very large.

Comment: Addins are application level. Ribbons are application level. Workbooks don't have addins or ribbons. Workbooks can load addins or modify ribbons.

Comment: You can customize the ribbon specific to workbooks.  My workbook removes all of the existing ribbon. I need to load the add-in when the workbook opens.  From my understanding, to load an add in should be: addins("Add-InName").installed = true; but the add in is still installed when the workbook opens, just hidden.